# Save a String[] with SharedPreferences and scan for every string in DynamoDB

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, sharedpreferences, amazon-dynamodb

I need to save a string to a string array when a button is being clicked. 

The string array should be saved for the next use, with SharedPreferences.

I want to get the string array from the SharedPreferences and search for every row that his attribute is equal to one string from the array, the second string...

This is my scan code:

```
DynamoDBScanExpression scan = new DynamoDBScanExpression;
Condition condition = new Condition()
    .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue(). // This is where I'm stuck. I don't know what to write here);
scan.addFilterCondition("name", condition);
List<Name> list = dbMapper.scan(name.class, scan);
```

What do I need to add to search for every item in the string array?

Comment: Did you try to loop through the items of array?

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use String set to achieve your functionality,

//put the string set

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(tag, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putStringSet(key, stringset);
editor.commit();
```

//get the string set

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(tag, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Set<String> someStringSet = pref.getStringSet(key);
```

Comment: In the `getStringSet` it requires also a string set with the key: `getStringSet (String key, Set<String> stringSet);`